# C++ while loop reading input

Tags: c++, file-io

I submitted this program and it works perfectly, but my teacher says that there is something wrong with my `while` loop even though I am getting the correct answers. Any tips or help?

What happens in the `while` loop when the end of file is reached and the `read` on line 43 becomes invalid? The way your program is structured you do not see the problem, but it is there. Should restructure the `while` loop to account for this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inputfile;

    char choice;


    int NumberOfIntegers = 0,
        SumOfIntegers = 0,
        Average = 0 ,
        LargestValue,
        SmallestValue,
        integer;

    inputfile.open("random.txt");

    if(!inputfile)
    {
        cout << "the file could not be open" << endl;
    }


    inputfile >> integer;

    //initialize smallest and largest
    SmallestValue = integer;
    LargestValue = integer;

    while(inputfile)
    {
        NumberOfIntegers++;
        SumOfIntegers = SumOfIntegers + integer;

        inputfile >> integer;
        if( integer > LargestValue || integer < SmallestValue)
        {

            if ( integer > LargestValue)
                LargestValue = integer;

            else 
                SmallestValue = integer;
        }
    }

    if(NumberOfIntegers > 0 )
    {
        Average = SumOfIntegers / NumberOfIntegers;
    }

    //closing input file
    inputfile.close();

    do
    {
        //Display Menu
        cout << "Make a selection from the list" << endl;
        cout << "A.   Get the largest Value" << endl;
        cout << "B.   Get the smallest Value" << endl;
        cout << "C.   Get the sum of the values" << endl;
        cout << "D.   Get the average of the values" << endl;
        cout << "E.   Get the number of values entered" << endl;
        cout << "F.   End this program" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Enter your choice -->  ";
        cin >> choice;

        cout << endl;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 'a':
        case 'A': cout << "The largest value is " << LargestValue << endl;
            break;

        case 'b':
        case 'B': cout << "The smallest value is " << SmallestValue << endl;
            break;

        case 'c':
        case 'C': cout << "The sum of the values entered is " << SumOfIntegers << endl;
            break;

        case 'd':
        case 'D': cout << "The average of the values entered is " << Average << endl;
            break;

        case 'e':
        case 'E': cout << "The number of values entered is " << NumberOfIntegers << endl;
            break;

        case 'f':
        case 'F': cout << "Program ending" << endl << endl;
                cin.ignore();
                cout << "\n\nPress Enter to end -->  ";
                cin.ignore();
                return 0;


        default: 
            cout << choice << " is an invalid value. " << endl;

        }

        cout << endl;

    } while( choice != 'f' || choice != 'F');


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You never check that the input succeeded before using the value.

Comment: You have a good teacher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "issue" I see is that you do not check the `bool` value of the stream after you read and before you process. To do this, you should put the read as the condition to the while loop.

```
if( ! inputfile >> integer )
{
    // error code (no integer in file)
    exit(0);
}

LargestValue = integer;
SmallestValue = integer;
NumberOfIntegers++;
SumOfIntegers = SumOfIntegers + integer;

while( inputfile >> integer )
{
    NumberOfIntegers++;
    SumOfIntegers = SumOfIntegers + integer;

    //inputfile >> integer;
    if( integer > LargestValue || integer < SmallestValue)
    {

        if ( integer > LargestValue)
            LargestValue = integer;

        else 
            SmallestValue = integer;
    }
}
```

---

In this scenario, the result should be the same with your program because if the `inputfile >> integer` failed, I believe `integer` keeps the same value as before so it would not effect `LargestValue` or `SmallestValue`. Then you check the stream so `NumberOfIntegers` and `SumOfIntegers` won't be updated, which is correct. The only time your program would give undefined results (for `LargestValue` and `SmallestValue`) is if the file doesn't start with an integer and simply by checking the first read and handling it appropriately this will be fixed.

Comment: I see so the condition of the while loop should only go off if an integer is read from the file. thanks a lot